# Not all checkbox values passed in a form when the very last ones are selected

Tags: php

I am working on a page that deals with a lot of data that the user can select what to pass to another page via a form. I have stumbled upon a big problem: When I want to pass the first items on the list the page does it flawlessly. However when I want to just select the very last items they're not being passed. Example

[image]

Can you please tell me what is going on? Thanks!

Code that creates the checkboxes. All 1085 of them:

```
echo "<form name='frmIns' method = 'POST' action = 'xx.php'>";

if(mysqli_num_rows($tablaO)>0)                                              
        {   
            $i = 0;
            $e = 1;
            while($registroO=mysqli_fetch_assoc($tablaO))                                                                   
            {   
                        if ($e%2== 0)
                        {
                            if($registroO['art_nota'] == 'Inventario' || $registroO['art_nota'] == 'Espera de Devolución' || $registroO['art_nota'] == 'Se va a Inventario') $color = 'e9bd15';
                            else $color='c5efef';
                        }else{
                            if($registroO['art_nota'] == 'Inventario' || $registroO['art_nota'] == 'Espera de Devolución' || $registroO['art_nota'] == 'Se va a Inventario') $color = 'e9bd15';
                            else $color='fdfdfd';
                            }


                $ValidacionID =  $registroO['art_id_verificador'];

                if($ISBN13r == null and $libro != null && $articulos == null)
                {   
                    $Idverificador = $registroO['art_id_verificador'];  
                    echo '<tr valign="top" class="registro" name="tr/'.$i.'" id="tr/'.$Idverificador.'" style="font-size: 11.5px; text-align: -webkit-center; background-color:#'.$color.'">
                        <td>'.$e.'</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chbArticulo[]" value="'.$Idverificador.'" onChange="cambia(this)" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="IDEs[]" value="'.$Idverificador.'" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="IdVerif[]" value="'.$ValidacionID.'" />
                        </td>'; 
                }else if($ISBN13r != null and $libro == null && $articulos == null){
                        echo'<tr valign="top" class="registro"  style="font-size: 11.5px; text-align: -webkit-center; background-color:#'.$color.'">
                        <td>'.$e.'</td>
                        <td></td>';                                                                     
                    }else{
                            $Idverificador = $registroO['art_id_verificador'];  
                            echo '<tr valign="top" class="registro" name="tr/'.$i.'" id="tr/'.$Idverificador.'" style="font-size: 11.5px; text-align: -webkit-center; background-color:#'.$color.'">
                                <td>'.$e.'</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="chbArticulo[]" value="'.$Idverificador.'-'.$Idverificador.'" onChange="cambia(this)" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="IDEs[]" value="'.$Idverificador.'" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="IdVerif[]" value="'.$ValidacionID.'" />
                                </td>'; 
                        }

                    echo'<td>'.$registroO['art_id_verificador'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['art_id_orden'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['art_fecha'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['art_N13'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['art_destino'].'</td>
                    <td style="'.($registroO['art_ofna_de'] != "" || $registroO['art_ofna_de'] != null ? "background-color:yellow;" : "").'">'.$registroO['art_ofna_de'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['art_ISBN'].'</td>
                    <td style = "max-width:250px; overflow:ellipsis;">'.$registroO['art_titulo'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['art_SKU'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['art_cantidad'].'</td>
                    <td>$'.number_format(($registroO['art_precio_logistica'] > 0 ? $registroO['art_precio_logistica'] : $registroO['art_precio']),2,".",",").'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['art_id_proveedor'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['art_nota'].'</td>
                    <td>'.($registroO['art_guia_ofna_arg'] == '' ? $registroO['art_guia_ofna'] : $registroO['art_guia_ofna_arg']).'</td>
                </tr>';
                $i=$i+ 1;
                $e=$e+ 1;   

                /*<td>'.$registroO['OfMi_pvp'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['OfMi_costUnitario'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['OfMi_TotalDeposito'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['OfMi_TotalOrden'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$registroO['OfMi_MarginProf'].'</td>*/
            }
        }   
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Not without any code, no.

Comment: @LJa added code

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski So I have to limit the number of records on each page?

Comment: There is a limit for php per post. The default is 1000. You can change your form to fit that limit or change the default value as stated by @MichaelBerkowski .

Comment: If your form requires that many checkboxes, don't change it, modify the setting in php.ini. But if you are writing code that needs to run on a diverse set of PHP installations you do not control, consider changing its architecture so it does not hit this common limit. Simplest is to set `max_input_vars=3000` in php.ini

Comment: @JasonK I also noticed the default number of items to be passed is 1000. However, I limited the number of items shown to 1000 and tried to pass the very last one to the other page and it still told me no items were passed. I tried selecting the checkbox in the middle (500) and got the same result. I told the other page to **echo** the number of items being passed and it told me there were none.

Comment: You have three fields per line. if you limit to 1000 lines. Then you have 3000 fields. Line 500 would be field 1500.

Comment: @JasonK you are totally right. I have commented out the last two inputs I don't need and the program works now. Thank you so much, everybody!